# Scrapy doesn't re-download a recently downloaded image

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Scrapy image pipeline states that it disables re-download of a recently downloaded images. How is this implemented ? Can it be disabled in dev ?

Src : http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html 
Avoid re-downloading media that was downloaded recently

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy checks file [stat](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L54-L64) before downloading.
You can set [`IMAGES_EXPIRES = 0`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/images.py#L49) to disable this feature for images.

Comment: or `IMAGES_EXPIRES` for the [ImagesPipeline](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/images.py#L33)